# Inconsistency of a function with input data types

Tags: haskell

**Don't waste your time. This was a huge mistake. I am not deleting it because of the valuable information in jon-purdy 's answer and for a perfect example of no thought put into a question.**

This simple reverse function is curious and frustrating.
It works with Int's but not with Char's.

```
rvl :: [a] → [a]
```

-- Works

```
rvl (x:xs) = x:rvl xs
take 5 $ rvl [0..]
```

[0,1,2,3,4]

-- doesn't work

```
take 5 $ rvl "abcde
```

"abcde"

-- un-stringing doesn't work either

```
rvl (x:xs) = (snd x):rvl xs
take 5 $ rvl (zip [0..] "abcde")
```

"abcde"

-- but it does with Int's

```
rvl (x:xs) = (fst x):rvl xs
take 5 $ rvl (zip [0..] "abcde")
```

[0,1,2,3,4]

-- swaping zip input yeilds same results

```
take 5 $ rvl (zip "abcde" [0..])
```

"abcde"

```
take 5 $ rvl (zip [0..] "abcde" )
```

[0,1,2,3,4]

Why? What have I got wrong?

Comment: How is `[0,1,2,3,4]` the reverse of `[0..]`?  I'm pretty sure your `rvl` function is just the identity on lists.

Answer (score 3):

```
rvl (x:xs) = x:rvl xs
```

This function doesn’t reverse a list. The equation says “If `rvl` is called with a non-empty list whose head is `x` and whose tail is `xs`, then return a list whose head is `x` and whose tail is `rvl xs`”. There is no case for the empty list.

Evaluation on `[0..]` proceeds like so:

- `rvl [0..]`
- = `0 : rvl [1..]`
- = `0 : 1 : rvl [2..]`
- = `0 : 1 : 2 : rvl [3..]`
- = `0 : 1 : 2 : 3 : rvl [4..]`
- …

So it’s the *identity function* on infinite lists:

```
> take 5 [0..]
[0,1,2,3,4]

> take 5 $ id [0..]
[0,1,2,3,4]

> take 5 $ rvl [0..]
[0,1,2,3,4]
```

And throws an exception on empty lists, or when it reaches the end of a finite list:

```
> rvl []
*** Exception: <interactive>:…:1-21: Non-exhaustive patterns in function rvl

> rvl ""
*** Exception: <interactive>:…:1-21: Non-exhaustive patterns in function rvl

> rvl [1, 2, 3]
[1,2,3*** Exception: <interactive>:…:1-21: Non-exhaustive patterns in function rvl

> rvl "abc"
"abc*** Exception: <interactive>:…:1-21: Non-exhaustive patterns in function rvl
```

You have avoided this error in your test cases by using `take`, coincidentally of the same length as the input, so the function never reaches this case. In the string example, you are effectively evaluating this:

```
> take 5 ('a' : 'b' : 'c' : 'd' : 'e' : error "Non-exhaustive patterns in function rvl")
"abcde"
```

The error isn’t thrown because in the base case, `take 0 undefined` = `[]`.

The solution is to implement both cases in your function:

```
rvl (x:xs) = …  -- What to do when list is non-empty.
rvl [] = …      -- What to do when list is empty.
```

Note that if you’re entering this in GHCi, you need to do one of the following:

- Enter it on one line with semicolons separating the equations:

  ```
  > rvl (x:xs) = …; rvl [] = …
  ```

  (You would also need to write curly braces around blocks such as `case … of { … }`, `… where { … }`, and `let { … } in …` expressions, but you won’t need any of them in this code.)
- Use the `:{` and `:}` commands to enter multiple lines:

  ```
  > :{
  | rvl (x:xs) = …
  | rvl [] = …
  | :}
  ```

  (Note that I’m assuming `:set prompt "> "` and `:set prompt-cont "| "` instead of the module list that displays by default. You can add those commands to your `.ghci` file to set the prompt whenever GHCi starts.)

Otherwise, if you enter an equation for `rvl (x:xs)` and then enter an equation for `rvl []`, the second will override the first, redefining the function. Enabling all warnings with `:set -Wall` can help catch confusing errors like this:

```
> :set -Wall
> rvl (x:xs) = x:rvl xs

<interactive>:…:1: warning: [-Wincomplete-patterns]
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘rvl’: Patterns not matched: []
```

As for how to reverse a list, consider:

- **Base case**—if you give `[]` to `rvl`, what do you expect to get back?
- **Recursive case**—if you give a list such as `[1, 2, 3]` to `rvl`, it will match `x:xs` and split the list into `x` = `1` and `xs` = `[2, 3]` (= `2 : (3 : [])`).

  Now suppose you already had `rvl` working, so `rvl [2, 3]` = `[3, 2]`. How would you combine `[3, 2]` with `1` to make `[3, 2, 1]`? How could you express this with `x` and `xs`?

  Notice that `=` in Haskell is an *equation*: the left and right sides mean the same thing. So if `rvl [2, 3]` = `[3, 2]`, and `xs` = `[2, 3]`, then `rvl xs` = `[3, 2]`.

Comment: My bad. I was working and working on another function. This is not important because I use `foldl (flip (:)) []`. I thought [Int] was comming out right but somewhere else. I think some remedial reading is order.  Thank you for your great response. I prefere lasy functions so don't use base case much. Like foldl an accumulater works always. I will not use `++`. Sometimes `x:_` comes out in reverse.

Comment: @fp_mora, how does having a base case relate to laziness?

Comment: @dfeuer The base case in infinite functions is just not necessary. A stream without end.

Comment: @fp_mora: If you want to work with infinite streams, it’s better to use a narrower input type like [`Stream` from `Data.Stream`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Stream-0.4.7.2/docs/Data-Stream.html), which can’t even represent finite lists, or a broader result type like `Maybe [a]`. In Haskell, we tend to prefer (as much as possible) working with *total* functions. Doing so gives you more of the benefits of the type system, simplifies equational reasoning about code, and in practice also helps to reduce mistakes.

Comment: @Jon Purdy Total functions are a priority with me. I am impressed with **Data.Stream** & **Data.InfList**. My problems are more algorithmic. I wanted to reverse an infinite list. So simple `rl xs = go [] xs where go a (x:xs) = b:go b xs where b = (x:a)`. It produces successive finite lists in reverse. `[[1],[2,1],[3,2,1]...]` so it streamlines a function to produce cross products of any type. Infinite lists in algorithms also reduce logic.
`plr xs ys = [ (a,b) | ls <- rl xs, (a,b) <- zip ls ys]` infinite cross products. I’ve another that `zip`s `inits` in a list comprehension. TY so very much

Comment: My bad. `rsl = tail.scanl (flip (:)) []` will do the same as `rl`